# How to implement action buttons around circular group in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I would like to implement an interface where the buttons need to be placed around a circular group object. All buttons need to be arranged around the circle in the circular order. It is similar to contacts interface provided by Apple Watch while side button is pressed. I keep thinking how apple would have implemented that. Watchkit framework doesn't allow the developer to set X&Y of the UI elements to position whereever we want. It would be great if someone can help me on how to do this technically.

PS:I need buttons around the circle as they have to be actionable.